# Avoid a certain range of numbers using a regex

Tags: regex

I would like to avoid the numbers in the range 64512 to 65534 with a regular expression. I have this regex:

> (6451[2-9]|645[2-9][0-9]|64[6-9][0-9]{2}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-4])

But it matches the numbers in the range 64512 to 65534 and not the opposite.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? There are better options to avoid number ranges, regex is not the right choice here

Comment: This will be used by Ruby and Python programs, however I need to use a regex because it is for a configuration file @baao

Comment: so check for `if number < 64512 and number > 65534:`

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^((?!64[5-9][1-9][2-9]|65[0-5][0-3][0-4])[0-9]*)$

Comment: Regular expressions are a poor choice here, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thank you very much @EJoshuaS